# Interchange the content of two string variable using Assembly language Program

Tags: assembly

I am new to AL programming. I was trying to interchange the contents of two string variables. I have one code with me which is to exchange two memory variables. Here is the code -

```
DATA SEGMENT
 NUM1 DB 9H
 NUM2 DB 7H
ENDS
CODE SEGMENT 
 ASSUME DS:DATA CS:CODE
START:
  MOV AX,DATA
  MOV DS,AX

  MOV AL,NUM1
  MOV BL,NUM2

  XCHG AL,NUM2
  XCHG BL,NUM1 

  MOV AH,4CH
  INT 21H     
ENDS
END START
```

Please let me know if I can make any changes here to get the exact output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    MOV    AL,NUM1
    MOV    BL,NUM2
    XCHG   AL,NUM2
    XCHG   BL,NUM1
```

Can be shortened to (when finished: same memory, different registers):

```
    MOV    AL,[NUM1]
    XCHG   AL,[NUM2]
    MOV    [NUM1],AL
```

But actually this longer version should perform even better (`XCHG` may be quite expensive instruction, as it is usually used together with `LOCK` prefix to synchronize things in multi-processor PCs, it is not used to "swap" values by compilers for decades, so it is not optimized for that in the modern x86 CPUs):

```
    MOV    AL,[NUM1]
    MOV    BL,[NUM2]
    MOV    [NUM2],AL
    MOV    [NUM1],BL
    ; when finished: same memory, but swapped AL<->BL
```

So that's about BYTE "variables". I would suggest you to actually stop thinking about `NUM1` as variable, and instead realize it is just symbolic label, an address into memory, where the following byte of machine code is put. And the following byte is defined by `DB 9h`, i.e. 8 bit value `9`. Also that's the reason why I prefer the original full Intel syntax, writing `mov al,[NUM1]` using square brackets to make it obvious when quickly glancing over source, that the instruction is accessing memory and that `NUM1` is address.

Some more examples, why "variables" way of thinking will overcomplicate it:

```
NUM1:
NUM2:   DB 9
```

Now you have two labels `NUM1` and `NUM2` pointing to the same byte, so you have "alias" for single "variable".

And finally strings...

```
InputString  DB "Hello$"
```

There's no such type as "string" in the CPU, so `InputString` can't be "string variable". It's just label to the next byte defined, and the next defined byte in machine code has value `'H'`, which is equal to `72` (check ASCII table for values of particular ASCII characters). That line will compile into machine code as 6 bytes with (hexa) values:

```
48 65 6C 6C 6F 24
```

So to "interchange content of two strings" you first need to know, that both target memory locations have enough bytes reserved. For example this:

```
String1 DB "a"
String2 DB "bc"
```

Is set up for disaster if you try to swap the content, as there's only 1 byte reserved for "String1" so when you will write `"bc"` into it, the `'c'` will actually land at the address `String2`

When you know you have enough memory reserved for both "strings", you need to copy byte contents from one to the other and other way around, you can actually even ignore the actual length of the strings, and just swap byte-by-byte total content of both buffers (like `buffer1 db 100 dup (?)` `buffer2 db 100 dup (?)` and then you swap 100 bytes between the two, not caring what is inside). Or you can optimize it by termination condition, when you reach "end of string" marker in the longer one.

Also note there's no string type in assembly, so how you mark end of your string is up to the code. The DOS output done by `int 21h,9` service does use character value `'$'`, but you can as well use the C-like strings terminated by value zero, or even use old Pascal way of having first byte of string reserved for length value, so `a = "Hello";` in Pascal was stored in memory as bytes `05 48 65 6C 6C 6F`. If you want to output resulting string with `int 21h,9` service, you will have to overwrite `'$'` terminators at their end. (also keep in mind the terminator of string is actually part of it, so 100 bytes of reserved memory is big enough for zero terminated string of length 99 characters).

Keep using debugger to watch values in your registers and memory, how they change with each instruction executed, it will accelerate tremendously the speed of your learning, as it's very "visual" (compared to reading the Intel instruction reference guide, which you should still read often).